# How can i make the target correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few thumbnail albums like

```
<div class="bigblock">
    <div class="thumbnails-block">
        <div class="thumbnails">
            imgs....
        </div>
<label for="fileupload" class="uploadbutton">Add</label>
<input class="file_upload" data-params="55" id="fileupload" style="visibility: hidden" type="file" multiple>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnails-block">
        <div class="thumbnails">
            imgs....
        </div>
<label for="fileupload" class="uploadbutton">Add</label>
<input class="file_upload" data-params="107" id="fileupload" style="visibility: hidden" type="file" multiple>
    </div>
</div>
```

And function to upload my files

```
$(function () {
        $('.file_upload').fileupload({
            add: function (e, data) {
                data.url = '/Files/UploadNewFile?' + $(e.target).data('params');
                data.submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

but it always gives me the first  data-params...
How can i make correct target for my code?

P.S. Im using BlueImg.Fileupload

Comment: Please always state which plugin you're using. Anyway, you can try using `.each()` first: `$('.file_upload').each(function () { $(this).fileupload(...) });`

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your recent question,  but here's one way to find words using wild cards as you specified: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EV9YP1